# Why does singular "mons" become plural "montes"?

Tags: pronunciation, declension, third-declension

Some singular third declension nouns, ending in *-s*, have a *t* in their stem, so:

> singular *mons* → plural *montes*
>   *infans* → *infantes*
>   *miles* → *milites*

I understand these to be examples of "lingual" or "T" mute stems, as described in [Allen & Greenough §56](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q7cAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA25) and [Gildersleeve §53](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU0BIAbE0SIC&pg=PA25).  Their analysis indicates that the *t* is dropped in the singular nominative, not added in the other cases.  But I'd like to know *why*: what are the linguistic and etymological reasons that the *t* is dropped in this kind of word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### A synchronic analysis: deletion of coronals before s within a syllable

In "[Latin Rhotacism for Real](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.225.8217&rep=rep1&type=pdf)," Kyle Gorman describes the deletion of /t/ in the nominative form of words like *mons, montis* as part of a larger pattern of deletion of coronal consonants which also applies to words like *pes, pedis* and *pollis, pollinis.* The main argument of the paper is that in Classical Latin, nouns with variation between *r* in some forms and and *s* in the nominative  should be analyzed according to this deletion rule, rather than according to a separate rule of intervocalic rhotacization.  So if Gorman is right, the deletion rule was still active in Classical Latin.

He notes that

> The sequence [ts] (from /ts/, or /ds/ and DEVOICING) does not occur in
>   word-final position (Devine and Stephens 1977:129), and its medial
>   occurrences are limited to syllable contact, allowing a rule of
>   deletion to be stated generally (cf. Heslin 1987:142).

This is the following "pre-/s/ deletion" rule:

> [CORONAL, +ORAL, -CONTINUANT] → ∅ / _s]<sub>σ</sub>

Gorman extends this rule to nouns with stems ending in *n* such as *pollis* and *sanguis* by removing the [+ORAL] specification.

> [CORONAL, -CONTINUANT] → ∅ / _s]<sub>σ</sub>

In order to prevent this extended rule from improperly deleting multiple consonants (such as the *n* in *mons*) Gorman proposes that the rule is "non-iterative" and "rightward-applying":

> In processing /mont-s/, the rule “sees” /t-s/, but the resulting [ns]
>   is not scanned by the rule.

This is the basis for his argument that forms like *mos, moris* can be analyzed using deletion of *r* before *s,* even though *r* is not deleted in the nominative forms of words with stems ending in *rt* such as *ars, artis.*

### Etymological analysis

Gorman's rule is clearly not based on the etymology of the words, since historically, the alternation of *s* and *r* did in fact originate from [rhotacism](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/153/9) and not from a historical process of r-deletion. (I don't know the historical origin of the nouns like *pollis* that have *n* in the stem but not in the nominative.)

Nonetheless, for nouns with with stems that end in -t- and -d-, the historical source of this variation seems to be similar to Gorman's synchronic rule. In some ancestor to Latin, a phonetic change occurred where word-final [ts] was eventually simplified to [s].

### Etymological consonant stem nouns

I found a paper that describes some theories about when this happened and what the intermediate steps were: "[The Proto-Indo-European *-VTs# clusters and the formulation of Szemerényi’s Law](http://www.academia.edu/18765354/The_Proto-Indo-European_-VTs_clusters_and_the_formulation_of_Szemer%C3%A9nyi_s_Law)," by Dariusz Piwowarczyk. The main example word he uses actually has "d" (*pod-s) but it seems that all scholars agree that underlying /ds/ was already devoiced to [ts] in PIE. There is disagreement about whether this [ts] was simplified to [s] in PIE or independently in the later branches of Indo-European.

### Etymological i-stem nouns

[TKR](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/817/why-does-singular-mons-become-plural-montes#comment1720_827) pointed out in the comments that Classical Latin also has many words that lose t in the nominative that come from Proto-Indo-European i-stem nouns. *Mons* and *sors* are two examples. The nominative forms of words like these seem to originate from syncope of *i*, followed by simplification of the cluster [ts] to [s]. Since this syncope was a Latin-specific development, and preceded the cluster simplification, these seem to require a Latin-specific rule at some point that changed [ts] to [s] in this context.

Comment: a side note. "According to Piwowarczyk, Oswald Szemerényi thinks" - 1. Oswald Szemerényi passed away in 1996. 2. Even Piwowarczyk clearly writes that Szemerényi seems to have changed his mind about Auslaut ts>s happening in PIE.

Answer (score 12):

Short answer: Latin does not allow the sequence *ts* (except in compound words), so an expected form like *monts* was remade into *mons*.

Of course, this only leads to the further question of *why* this sequence was disallowed in Latin, which is much more difficult to answer. Every language has a set of preferences as to which sequences of sounds it does and doesn't permit -- this is called *phonotactics*. But the reasons why one language's phonotactic rules are different from another's are usually hard to state.

In the particular case of *ts*, we have two adjacent consonants that are phonetically similar: they're both coronals, i.e. are both pronounced with the tip of the tongue at or near the teeth. This is the kind of environment where loss of one of the two sounds ("assimilatory loss") is a linguistically common pattern. A possible explanation is that the similarity in articulation makes it hard to hear that there are two distinct consonants there, so the whole sequence might often have been perceived as just an [s] sound -- and if this happened often enough, speakers would eventually forget that there had ever been a *t* there at all.

Comment: It's actually very hard to say "monts" naturally in such a way that you actually hear the 't' :)

Comment: @CompuChip Not THAT hard. You say "pants" and "dents," right?

Comment: Sadly, I am a noob and cannot comment nor upvote, but I am compelled to point out that [Joel Derfner's](http://latin.stackexchange.com/users/68/joel-derfner) retort is not quite applicable, for example what is the pronunciation difference between: CHANTS and CHANCE or DENTS and DENSE

Comment: Welcome to the site! Perhaps you and I will have to agree to disagree—if you told me you were going to Target and asked me if I wanted anything and I said, "Can you bring me back a pair of pants?" you'd be unlikely to bring me back two Bundt cake tins (and vice versa). Certainly the difference is small, but if it leans one way or the other, I'd say that epenthesis is far more likely to add a t to "chance" so that it's pronounced "chants" than remove one from "chants" so it's pronounce "chance." (Of course, I'd appreciate Bundt cake tins OR clothing, either way. :) )

Comment: "Latin does not allow the sequence ts". What about etsi?

Comment: @fdb: Fair enough, but that's a transparent compound of *et si*, so is a somewhat different case. (Who knows if the Romans would have written it *etsi* or *et si*?)

Comment: @fdb I've added "except in compound words" to the answer.

Comment: There are only [7 words](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=ts&lang=la) in L&S that have the *ts* combination, all of which are compounds.

Answer (score 4):

The loss of the final consonant of –t stems before the –s suffix of the nominative singular is not specific to Latin, but is general Indo-European. It is thus not correct to try to explain it in terms of some inner-Latin exclusion law. It is something that Latin has inherited from IE.

Example: IE *nepōt-, nom. sing. *nepōt-s > *nepōs > Iranian *napāh > Avestan napå. See Hoffmann/Forssman, Avestische Laut- und Flexionslehre, p.139.

Comment: I didn't know that this loss of *t* is a more common Indo-European trait. But being Indo-European does not make it non-Latin; if Latin inherited a phonetic rule from PIE, it is still a rule in Latin. Some study Latin without a wider IE linguistic context, and for them this point of view is natural.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. I contest that "it is still a rule in Latin". Witness etsi, postsum, postscribo etc.

Comment: One could view those as compound words (*et-si*, *post-sum*, *post-scribo*) and consider *-ts-* to be preserved in such situations against the general rule. Whether or not it was ever an active rule in Latin, I still find the rule useful for understanding Latin declension. It may have exceptions, but it isn't pointless. Nevertheless, it is interesting to know the origin of this sound change.

Comment: If this is intended as a correction of my answer (in which case I think it would be better as a comment), I don't see the contradiction. Synchronic phonotactic constraints often have diachronic origins.

Comment: Btw, the fact that this is still an active rule in Latin can be seen from its application in words that were not t-stems in PIE, which is the case of *mons* itself: it's a *-ti-* stem, whose PIE nominative would have been *montis*, but became *mons* by a Latin-specific syncope change.

Comment: @TKR. Yes, mons is historically an IE -i stem, *mnti-. But in Latin its paradigm has been completely revamped by analogy to -t stems like nepot-, nom. sing. nepos. From a purely Latin synchronic point of view there is no reason to regard mons as an -i stem.

Comment: @fdb Agreed; my point was that the t-loss rule, though originating in PIE, is still fully synchronically productive in Latin.

Comment: @sumelic: Maybe not *montis*, but we do have *sortis* in Plautus for later *sors*.

Comment: @sumelic. The etymology of nox is actually hotly contested. Have a look at the entry in de Vaan.

Comment: @fdb references? examples?

Comment: @AlexB. I have added an example in Indo-Iranian, and a reference.

Comment: @fdb And? The reference you mentioned is slightly tangential to our discussion here. What evidence can you share with us that regressive assimilation ts>ss>s happened already in PIE (**viz. nom.sg.!**) and not in individual languages?

Comment: @AlexB: I just found a paper that seems to argue against dating this change to PIE, while acknowledging that some scholars do so: "[The Proto-Indo-European *-VTs# clusters and the formulation of Szemerényi’s Law](http://www.academia.edu/18765354/The_Proto-Indo-European_-VTs_clusters_and_the_formulation_of_Szemerényi_s_Law)", by Dariusz Piwowarczyk

Comment: @sumelic Thanks, I'll read it later today with all the references mentioned. So far, I'd stick to "the minimal account" of Szemerényi's law.

Comment: Hittite t-stems have a nom. sg. in -z(a) [ts], which argues against t-loss in PIE (unless you want to say that these forms are analogical from the oblique cases).