# 'Fomites'? From 'fomes'?

Tags: etymology, morphology, suffixes, third-declension

Of the many candidates for 'word of the year', 'fomites' is a semifinalist for sure (with the added flavor of multiple pronunciations).

But why the dental '-t-' in the plural? What is the pattern? Is there a rule in Latin in this obscure-to-me declension that I missed?

From OED (English):

> Origin: A borrowing from Latin. Etymon: Latin fōmes. Etymology: <
> classical Latin fōmes (genitive fōmitis) kindling, in later use also
> stimulus (2nd cent. a.d.), in post-classical Latin also morbific
> matter (of a disease) (1546 in G. Fracastoro, or earlier) < the base
> of fovēre to cherish, warm (see fovent adj.); **the origin of the
> dental suffix is unclear.**

Origin unclear? Is it really unclear? /s/ and /t/ are both in the dental area. So what is the historical connection and what is the pattern?

Full disclosure: I'm a little out of my depth here. I'm just sorta passing this on from a conversation in ELU chat).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The etymological derivation of the noun *fōmes, fōmitis* from the base of the verb *foveo* is too difficult for me to answer. So in this post, I'll focus on something else in your post that I think I might be able to clarify: how the different forms of the noun are related to each other in Latin.

A fair number of Latin nouns inflect like *fōmes,* with a nominative singular form ending in *-es* /es/ and a genitive singular form ending in *-itis* /itis/. According to the regular patterns of Latin declension, the occurrence of *-it-* in the genitive singular allows you to infer the occurrence of *-it-* in all other forms of the word aside from the nominative singular: this includes both plural forms such as *fōmitēs* and singular forms such as *fōmitem* and *fōmitī.*

### You can analyze *fōmes* as a noun with a stem ending in |et|

Even though the nominative singular form *fōmes* has no [t] in its "surface realization", we can analyze *fōmes* as having an "underlying form" built on a stem ending in |et|. (In this post, I will use bars, as with |et|, to represent "underlying forms" that may contain sounds or sequences of sounds that never show up in pronunciation, versus slashes, as with /foːmes/, to represent sequences of sounds that would be audibly pronounced.)

#### a rule forbidding /ts/ gives *fōmes* from |foːmet-s|

Starting from the stem |foːmet|, we would get |foːmet-s| by adding the nominative singular suffix |s|. But [Latin does not allow the sequence [ts] to occur](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/818/9) (except for across a word boundary, or within a few compound words such as *etsi* that historically contained a word boundary). In contexts where the addition of a suffix would create the forbidden sequence /ts/ or /ds/, Latin regularly replaces the sequence with either the geminate /ss/, or with a single /s/ in contexts where a geminate /ss/ would also be forbidden. Since geminate /ss/ is not allowed at the end of a word in post-Plautine Latin, |foːmet-s| is simplified to /foːmes/.

#### a rule reducing |e| to /i/ gives *fōmitēs* from |foːmet-eːs|

The oblique forms of the word, such as *fōmitēs,* can be derived from the stem |foːmet| by a rule of vowel reduction in non-initial open syllables. Before a vowel-initial suffix such as the nominative plural ending |-eːs|, the final |t| of the stem is syllabified into a different syllable from the preceding short vowel |e|. When the short vowel |e| occurs at the end of a syllable that is not the first or last syllable of a word, it often changes into the short vowel /i/.

There are many other examples of words that show this kind of alternation between /e/ in a syllable with a final consonant and /i/ in a syllable without one.  This is covered in "[Aspects of the phonology and morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf)" (2016), by András Cser, section 5.1.2.1. (pages 90-92).

However, the reduction of |e| to /i/ does have some exceptions: *hebes, hebetis; impes, impetis; indiges, indigetis; interpres, interpretis; perpes, perpetis; praepes, praepetis; seges, segetis; teges, tegetis; teres, teretis.* The *-es, -etis* words are greatly outnumbered by *-es, -itis* words that do show the /e/~/i/ alternation.

Some or all of the words in this list with exceptional genitive singular forms in /-etis/ could possibly be explained by adding further conditions to the rule of vowel reduction. Cser lists *seges, teges, hebes, perpes* and provides the generalization that this pattern is found in words "with stem shapes of the form C[e]C(C)[et]-"; he also indicates that the fact that *perpes* is a prefixed word is relevant (92).

Comment: Excellent exposition. "the origin of the dental suffix is unclear" seems to be clarified by this. I wonder if the '-it-' suffix is in fact a suffix or has a particular meaning or precursor.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you and the OED are talking about two different things. As you can see from the very same passage, the genitive is *fomitis*. This is par for the course for 3rd declension nouns. You find the root from the genitive, not the nominative. In this case, the foot is fomit-, whereupon you add the 3rd declension endings, -is, -i, -em, -e, -es, etc. You see this all the time, like in *aetas*, genitive *aetatis* or *miles*, genitive *militis*. There's nothing special about *fomes* in this regard.

The OED is instead asking why stem is dental at all. The word is derived *foveo*, and I presume the editors of the OED mean that it ought to have been formed without the dental in it, such as *fames, famis*. To this it was probably just formed on analogy with words like *miles, militis* above. I'll let others speculate on why the stem is etymologically the way it is, but with respect to its form, it is not unusual in Latin at all.

Comment: Excellent. I was unsure of an analogy but it is clear now there is a pattern.