# A software in Latin?

Tags: resource-request, modern-life

I visited a webpage translating a bunch of IT words into Latin, so I know the vocabulary does exist.

As I'm an avid language learner, sometimes I download apps and software in a foreign language to train and teach myself. Sometimes I just change the interface, switching it to a different language.

But what about Latin? **Does a PC software or an Android app exist in Latin?**

(I think it is more likely to exist on a Linux-based OS)

Comment: Does Duolingo count? It's…not particularly high-quality, but it exists.

Comment: No, because Duo is a software to learn Latin (I think you are a bit severe with it by the way), it's not a software with a Latin interface, it was what I meant.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/is-there-an-operating-system-entirely-in-latin

Comment: Sorry, but what is the relationship with my question? Duolingo is not what I asked, not how Duolingo behaves.

Comment: I know there are several chrome plugins that replace words of the page, with their translations in a language that you choose.  I can't attest to the quality of those however. By the way, would you mind linking the web page with the IT words translated?

Comment: That's not what I ask, but I take this opportunity to ask you if you have found a good replacement for Readlang?

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I know the Java edition of Minecraft has an extensive Latin translation, though it's in need of much revision.

Comment: As far as I know, it’s also possible to design a custom language pack; one could design their own improved Latin language pack and circumvent the problems of the current one.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.romhacking.net/?page=translations&genre=&platform=&status=&languageid=20&perpage=20&title=&author=&transsearch=Go) is a list of NES and SNES video games in Latin. ([source](https://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?t=39499))

Notice [Ubuntu](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/is-there-an-operating-system-entirely-in-latin) has an option to have the system in Latin but is unfinished. The modular nature of Ubuntu means you can have some pieces software of it fully in Latin. If you follow the link, you can see there is still no package completely in Latin. It's an open-source project so help with translations are welcome!