# Was the letter phi used in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, greek, new-latin, alphabet

Is there any evidence of the Greek letter phi being borrowed to write Latin words of Greek origin as *φilosoφia* for example?

The question is not restricted to Classical Latin.

Comment: Well there would be nothing strange about borrowing a letter, it is what was done with y

Comment: I see - I misread your question. You may want to read more about which Greek letters were borrowed in Latin - and which ones were not - here https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/193/39